# Name for program that tabulates file differences

Tags: version-control

I'm interested in creating a customized versioning control tool. I would like to know if there is an open source tool that can compare 2 different text or binary files (will probably be similar with a few modifications), generate some kind of object that describes the changes/differences, and produces a file I can store into my tracking database. Obviously I would want the program to do the reverse: given the original file and my difference-file, I can regenerate the updated file.

Is there a name for a function like this?

Answer (score 0):

I would use the command line program `git`. It can display file differences in a well defined format. These 'diff' files can be used to change one file to the next in the sequence.